# linear equation that curves one line to another fails when the lines overlap.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a problem stemming from an engineering field.

We have a linear equation which acts as a limit for control software. There is an update to this that allows the machine to perform outside these bounds, but being cautious we want to scale back the predicted performance so we do not over predict in this region.

Call the old limit $L_{old}$. The factor we apply so that $L_{new} = C_L L_{old}$ will be $C_L$ (the correction to the limit, with is greater or equal to $1$). The variable being bound by the limit is $x$. So, it used to be that $x$ could not be greater than $L_{old}$, now $x$ can range all the way up to $x=L_{new} = C_L L_{old}$. $C_P$ is an additive correction. So $performance_{new} = (1 + C_P)performance_{old}$

I am trying to develop a correction to performance $C_P$ so that the following is true.

1. $C_P(x \le L_{old}) = 0$ (I.E. there is no correction applied up until when we hit our old limit)
2. $C_P(x = L_{new}) = 1$ (the correction is at its maximum when we hit our new limit)
3. $C_L \ge 1$

So far I have tried the following

$C_P = \frac {\frac{x}{L_{old}}-1}{C_L-1}$

The problem is that $C_L$ can equal $1$. When the old and the new limit are the same limit, we should have that $\forall x ,C_P(x) = 0$ instead we have a big fat discontinuity.

Is there any way of expressing this in a simple mathematical function?

Comment: I didn't read all of your question, but it sounds like you might want a 'sigmoid function'. There's a good Wikipedia page listing a bunch of examples.

Comment: @user275313 I am looking at the Wikipedia page. Trying to figure out if a sigmoid function can be used.